# What does Backquote (`) mean in my expression?

Tags: syntax

When producing data,

```
data = Table[{n/100, (2 n)/100 + 1 + 0.1` RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {n, 0,
100}];
```

What does the ` mean here? Does it simply mean multiplication? Because if I delete it, the code seems to do the same work.

Comment: see [NumberMarks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberMarks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 0.1 is a machine precision floating point number. What you show is equivalent to

```
.1 // FullForm
```

> ```
> 0.1`
> ```

Note: What you show is equivalent to

```
data = 
  Table[{n/100, (2 n)/100 + 1 + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}, {n, 0, 100}];
```